# Google Maps API - Stops after 11 time ran on single page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I'm running through my posts on wordpress and getting them to show up on google maps but when it gets to number 12 in the list it throws back an error the 12 one in the list is not set up any diffrent to the rest. I have removed what was number 12 and replaced with a new one.

```
function initMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('club-map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: { lat: 41.383682, lng: 2.176591 },
        styles: [{elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#212121"}]},{elementType:"labels.icon",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#757575"}]},{elementType:"labels.text.stroke",stylers:[{color:"#212121"}]},{featureType:"administrative",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#757575"}]},{featureType:"administrative.country",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#9e9e9e"}]},{featureType:"administrative.land_parcel",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{featureType:"administrative.locality",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#bdbdbd"}]},{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#757575"}]},{featureType:"poi.park",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#181818"}]},{featureType:"poi.park",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#616161"}]},{featureType:"poi.park",elementType:"labels.text.stroke",stylers:[{color:"#1b1b1b"}]},{featureType:"road",elementType:"geometry.fill",stylers:[{color:"#2c2c2c"}]},{featureType:"road",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#8a8a8a"}]},{featureType:"road.arterial",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#373737"}]},{featureType:"road.highway",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#3c3c3c"}]},{featureType:"road.highway.controlled_access",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#4e4e4e"}]},{featureType:"road.local",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#616161"}]},{featureType:"transit",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#757575"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{color:"#000000"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#3d3d3d"}]}]
    });

    var address;
    <?php
        // Add club pins
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'clubs', 'posts_per_page' => '25','nopaging' => true, 'order' => 'ASC');
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while(have_posts()){
            the_post();
    ?>
        address = "<?= get_field('address'); ?>";
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status){
            console.log('result');
            console.log(results);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon: '<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/dist/images/map-pin.png',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                clubId: <?= get_the_ID(); ?>,
                name: '<?= addslashes(get_the_title()); ?>',
                age: <?= get_field('age_requirement'); ?>,
                logo: '<?= get_field('club_logo'); ?>',
                cost: '<?= number_format(get_field('membership_cost'), 2); ?>',
                rating: <?= get_field('rating'); ?>
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                clubDetails(marker.clubId,marker.name,marker.age,marker.logo,marker.cost,marker.rating);
            });

            var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<?= addslashes(get_the_title()); ?>',
                map: map,
                // position: homeLatlng
            });

            marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

            marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            })
        });
    <?php } ?>
 }
```

I get this error in my console

```
(index):987 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at (index):987
    at geocoder.js:5
    at FU (geocoder.js:3)
    at Object.HU.geocode (geocoder.js:5)
    at Array.<anonymous> (js?key=AIzaSyAgDZJic9rlx9ZV9PRynFo76d9gSlAE-UY&callback=initMap:133)
    at js?key=AIzaSyAgDZJic9rlx9ZV9PRynFo76d9gSlAE-UY&callback=initMap:124
    at Object.<anonymous> (js?key=AIzaSyAgDZJic9rlx9ZV9PRynFo76d9gSlAE-UY&callback=initMap:62)
    at js?key=AIzaSyAgDZJic9rlx9ZV9PRynFo76d9gSlAE-UY&callback=initMap:124
    at js?key=AIzaSyAgDZJic9rlx9ZV9PRynFo76d9gSlAE-UY&callback=initMap:62
    at js?key=AIzaSyAgDZJic9rlx9ZV9PRynFo76d9gSlAE-UY&callback=initMap:124
```

And this is the line it is pointing too

```
position: results[0].geometry.location,
```

**EDIT**

This is what my `console.log(results)` looks like it also includes the error https://gyazo.com/b3c91e3feb34ea61068bb1e0102ec554

**EDIT V2**

I have commented out the `//position: results[0].geometry.location,` and after the 11 time it runs it its just not giving back a result

Comment: @Dipak How will i be able to know that their i a lat and a lng from the result. It wont even print the results after that error on the 12th one

Comment: @Dipak I have posted the console.log results now

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the GeoCoder Method Section, check once by replacing this one with your code, let me know if there,

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    var markers = results.map(function(location, i) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: location.geometry.location,
            icon: '<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/dist/images/map-pin.png',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            clubId: <?= get_the_ID(); ?>,
            name: '<?= addslashes(get_the_title()); ?>',
            age: <?= get_field('age_requirement'); ?>,
            logo: '<?= get_field('club_logo'); ?>',
            cost: '<?= number_format(get_field('membership_cost'), 2); ?>',
            rating: <?= get_field('rating'); ?>
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<?= addslashes(get_the_title()); ?>',
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

            var iwOuter = jQuery('.gm-style-iw');

            // Reference to the div that groups the close button elements.
            var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

            // Apply the desired effect to the close button
            iwCloseBtn.remove()
        });

        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        })

        return marker;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm getting the same error again after the 11th call

Comment: `address = "7 Carrer del Doctor Dou, Barcelona 08001, Spain";
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      var markers = results.map(function(location, i) {`